# How to create a proper Makefile and does the order of dependecies matter?

Tags: c, makefile

I have 5 files that I must use makefile to create one file.

```
student.c has #include "student.h"

linkedlist.c has #include "linkedlist.h"

and main has #include "linkedlist.h" and #include "student.h"

student.c
student.h
linkedlist.c
linkedlist.h
main.c
```

I dont know if the order matters to resolve the dependencies. 
I guess what I am really asking is what does bottom up dependency mean??? 
Can someone clarify how to use makefile correctly for future projects?

Comment: This question looks similar to yours. And the answer is much more complex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838040/how-exactly-do-i-use-a-makefile?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you need to know is:

```
#You can make some const variables like `CC = gcc` 
#and use them in the Makefile like that `$(CC)` 
#(you basically wrap the variable with brackets and 
#put a dollar sign before it).

CC = gcc  

#The order is crutial in a makefile. 

# First of all you want to compile `main` using objects 
# which are yet to be linked.
main: student.o linkedlist.o
    # Line below is a command 
    # that is already well known to you I guess: "gcc -o main ..." 
    $(CC) -o main student.o linkedlist.o

# If makefile doesn't have the newest version of a .o file, 
# then it goes to lines below 
# to find out, how can it obtain the newest version 
# of student.o or linkedlist.o

# This is how it can produce the .o file:
student.o: student.c
    $(CC) -c student.c 
    # -c flag is crutial here, because it means that you want to create
    # a .o (object) file. Not an executable program.

# Same with linkedlist.c:
linkedlist.o: linkedlist.c
    $(CC) -c linkedlist.c
```

I hope it works, I haven't tested it. Correct me if I made any mistake, please.

---

**One more thing: remember that you have to use TABS instead of SPACES to indent lines.**

Comment: "you have to use TABS instead of SPACES to indent lines" --- The creator of make preemptively solved the tabs vs spaces issue.